# Error al aplicar operaciones con fechas usando paquete lubridate: argumento no-numérico para operador binario

Tags: r, date, rstudio, ggplot2

Tengo un dataframe en R (trabajo en Rstudio), donde cada fila es una vaca y las columnas indican las fechas de cada parto.

Quiero graficar la distribución por fecha de parto para todas las vacas en cada columna con fechas y después realizar otras operaciones matemáticas en dichas columnas.

---

La tabla tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
    dvp3   prop  arete  fecha_nac     lact_1     lact_2     lact_3     lact_4     lact_5
1  930.5  10002    101 2012-01-20 2014-01-15 2014-12-24 2016-01-25       <NA>       <NA>  
2 1229.6  10002   1019 2007-12-24 2010-01-31 2010-12-30 2012-08-12 2013-11-02 2014-10-06   
3    0.0  10002     10 2010-02-26 2012-03-17 2014-06-11       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>   
4    0.0  10002   1020 2012-07-09 2014-04-27 2015-03-23       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>   
5 1574.4  10002    102 2008-10-26 2010-12-14 2012-09-16 2014-06-05       <NA>       <NA>   
6    0.0  10002    105 2014-02-26 2015-12-04       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
```

Las columnas "lac" corresponden a fechas de partos desde el primero hasta el quinto.

Las fechas las edité con lubridate de esta manera:

```
library(lubridate)
ymd(datosped06_2$lact_1)
```

La columna aparece codificada como fecha, al usar la función "class":

```
class(ymd(datosped06_2$lact_1))
[1] "Date"
```

Pero al realizar los gráficos de distribución

```
boxplot(datosped06_2$lact_1)
ggplot(data = datosped06_2) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = nlaca, fill = lact_1), position = "dodge")
```

Sale esto:

```
boxplot(datosped06_2$lact_1)
Error in x[floor(d)] + x[ceiling(d)] : 
  argumento no-numérico para operador binario

ggplot(data = datosped06_2) +
+   geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = nlaca, fill = lact_1), position = "dodge")
Error in abs(x) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

No consigo hacer ninguna operación matemática ni gráfico sobre las columnas que tienen fechas.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

Dale una mirada al paquete [lubridate](https://evoldyn.gitlab.io/evomics-2018/ref-sheets/R_lubridate.pdf)

Algunas opciones para trabajar con fechas y realizar cálculos básicos, son, por ejemplo:

Vector con fechas codificadas como año-mes-dia

```
library(lubridate)

fecha <- seq(from = ymd("2000-01-01"),
             to = ymd("2000-12-28"),
             length.out = 30)
```

Las fechas pueden ser usadas para realizar cálculos

```
summary(fecha)

sd(fecha)

mean(fecha) - sd(fecha)
```

Hay funciones para sumar o restar días, meses, minutos...

```
mean(fecha) - days(109)

mean(fecha) + months(1)

as_date("2021-10-22") + months(2)
```

Las siguientes lineas de código crean columnas indicando que observaciones están en un intervalo de tiempo. El primero crea columna indicando fechas anteriores a 2000-05-15, el segundo crea columna indicando fechas superiores a 2000-10-15

```
interv_inf <- fecha < as_date("2000-05-15")

interv_sup <- fecha > as_date("2000-10-15")
```

Incluyendo todos los vectores en una tabla

```
df <- data.frame(fecha, interv_inf, interv_sup)

df
tail(df)
#        fecha interv_inf interv_sup
# 25 2000-10-26      FALSE       TRUE
# 26 2000-11-08      FALSE       TRUE
# 27 2000-11-20      FALSE       TRUE
# 28 2000-12-03      FALSE       TRUE
# 29 2000-12-15      FALSE       TRUE
# 30 2000-12-28      FALSE       TRUE
```

Para transformar las columnas en formato de fecha hay que asignarles un nombre. Un ejemplo con tus datos:

```
library(lubridate)
datosped06_2$lact_1 <- ymd(datosped06_2$lact_1)
```

Luego puedes confirmar si los datos fueron transformados en el formato deseado

```
class(datosped06_2$lact_1)
```

Comment: Estimado José, antes que nada te agradezco tu respuesta. Estaba leyendo tus comentarios y tengo una duda, en el primer código cuando generas una secuencia de fechas con una longitud de 30 con el formato año mes y día; tendría que ordenar primero mis fechas por columna y así establezco la primer fecha y la última fecha? porque me pone a dudar si ese valor de 30 lo tendría que modificar con respecto al numero de observaciones en mi columna de fecha de primer parto y si tengo que incluir los valores NA (que corresponden aquellos animales que no reportan una fecha al primer parto).

Comment: @sanunso76: incluí un ejemplo general de cómo trabajar con fechas con el paquete lubridate. Si necesitas más ayuda con tus análisis debes incluir un ejemplo con parte de tus datos, explicando claramente lo que quieres hacer y un ejemplo de cómo quieres transformar tu tabla. El ejemplo de la tabla puede ser con datos fictícios. Lo importante es que las personas puedan replicar tu ejemplo y ofrecer soluciones.

Comment: Estoy incluyendo parte de mis datos:

Comment: @sanunso76: para incluir los datos puedes usar la función [dput](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput) en R sobre la base de datos completa o sobre un fragmento de esta: `dput(datosped06_2)`.